# jQuery Validation Plugin - refresh captcha work only once

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, captcha

I'm using custom captcha with [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)

My configuration looks like this:

```
$('#contactform').validate({
        onkeyup: function(element, event) {
            $(element).valid();
        },
        errorElement: 'span',
        rules: {
            contactform_captcha: {
                minlength: 6,
                maxlength: 6,
                required: true,
                remote: /path/to/captcha-check.php
            },
        },
        messages: {
            contactform_captcha: {
                required: "No code, no email",
                minlength: function () {
                    return [
                    'Enter at least ' + (6 - parseInt($('#contactform_captcha').val().length)) +
                    ' more character(s) to go.'];
                },
                remote: function () {
                    $("#captchaimage").attr("src", /path/to/new/captcha.php+"?r=" + Math.random());
                    return ['Wrong code, therefore try again'];
                }
            },
        },
        success: function(label) {
            label.addClass("valid").text("Well done!")
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {

            //submit form

        }    
    });
    $('span[class^="error"]:not(.valid)').remove();
```

What this code do is verify if there are 6 characters, then sends these 6 characters to `captcha-check.php`. If everything is ok `captcha-check.php` will return `true`, else it will return `false` and this function is called then:

```
remote: function () {
    $("#captchaimage").attr("src", /path/to/new/captcha.php+"?r=" + Math.random());
    return ['Wrong code, therefore try again'];
}
```

On `false`, message function will update new `src` of image `#captchaimage`. Everything works, but only for the first time. I guess that remote response message is cached.

Also if i output `Math.random()` in remote remote response message, it will not update and there perhaps maybe is problem.

Comment: As written, your `remote` method is called on every keystroke and therefore, you're trying to change the captcha image on every keystroke.  It would be impossible for the user to enter the correct captcha code in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
messages: {
    contactform_captcha: {
        ....
        remote: function () {
            $("#captchaimage").attr("src", /path/to/new/captcha.php+"?r=" + Math.random());
            return ['Wrong code, therefore try again'];
        }
    }       
}
```

I suggest that you convert your `Math.random()` function to PHP and into your server side script, rather than having `+"?r=" + Math.random()` in your JavaScript, which is not secure.  After all, nothing is preventing somebody from over-riding `Math.random()` and sending any number they wish.

And since the `messages` option is only meant for generating custom messages, you should trigger the new captcha image upon the `success` response from the `remote` method instead.

Something a lot more like this...

```
rules: {
    contactform_captcha: {
        // minlength: 6,   // <-- handle this in your PHP for remote
        // maxlength: 6,   // <-- handle this in your PHP for remote
        // rangelength: [6,6],  // <-- same as two rules above
        required: true,
        remote: {
            url: '/path/to/captcha-check.php',
            success: function (response) {
                if (response != true) {
                   // trigger a new captcha code from here
                   $("#captchaimage").attr("src", "/path/to/new/captcha.php")
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
```

[As per the documentation for the `remote` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/):

> The [server] response is evaluated as JSON and must be `true` for valid elements,
>   and can be any `false`, `undefined` or `null` for invalid elements, using
>   the default message; **or a string**, eg. "That name is already taken, try
>   peter123 instead" to display as the error message.

You could also leverage this to generate custom messages on your server side.  In fact, since you need to call `remote` on this field anyway, all validation rules (`minlength`, `maxlength`, etc.) for your `contactform_captcha` field could be done server-side.  Whatever string is returned from the server will automatically become the error message.

**An important note:**

I would disable `onkeyup` validation for the `contactform_captcha` field, otherwise, you're going to call the `remote` method on every keystroke thereby checking the captcha code before the user finishes entering the full captcha code.  This will be a major issue since it's impossible for the user to match a captcha that changes on every keystroke.

```
onkeyup: function(element, event) {
    if ($(element).attr('name') != 'contactform_captcha') {
        $(element).valid();
    }
},
```